# Azure Devops Rest API - Find out Queue Jobs on a specific Agent Pool

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

From the Azure-DevOps Rest API documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 there is no clear way to query for the Jobs running on a specific Agent Pool.

Went through the different API calls plus fiddler.

`curl -u X:X https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?api-version=5.1-preview.1` --> gets the running agents on a specific agent pool

What is the REST API call to get jobs on the queue on a specific Agent Pool? I expected a JSON output with the jobs running on a specific Agent Pool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all the jobs requests in specific pool with this Rest API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organiztion}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/jobrequests
```

Now you can filter only the running job, how? to the running job there is no `result` property, so in PowerShell you can do sometnig like this:

```
$json = $jobs | ConvertFrom-Json
$runningJobs = $json.Where({ $_.PSobject.Properties.name -notcontains "result" })
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56850955/2586938) does not work with the current API version 7.1.

But in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/webdevops/azure-devops-exporter/issues/17#issuecomment-554900449) I found another URL variant of this undocumented API which still worked in my tests.

`https://{organization}.visualstudio.com/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolid}/jobrequests`

You can then filter items which have `assignTime` not set. These are the pending jobs.